# Where can I find a free xform editor?

Tags: html, xml, xforms

I am new to xform. I have a project and I have no idea on where to write my code. So any help? (I am working on windows XP SP2).

Answer (score 1):

Try a search for IBM Visual XForms Designer. it is a plug-in for eclipse.

add this site to ur software update site in eclipse 
http://awwebx04.alphaworks.ibm.com/ettktechnologies/updates
and install it.

**Edit by @tostao**: Now it is [IBM Forms](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/products/forms/) and it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for: [**Oryx: XForms**](http://bpt.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/Oryx/XForms)

Comment: I agree that project is not useful

Comment: Would be useful if you explained why?

Comment: +1 to Naeem, maybe it was not for you but explain as other may want to know... and I'm not sure it deserve a -1 on answer... It's not like if we know you tried it.

Comment: Oryx Online Services is discontinued as of 16.12.2012.

Answer (score 0):

One possible editor: 
http://build.opendatakit.org/

but it is not fully functional

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms) - an open source client-side implementation, or [this](http://code.google.com/p/ubiquity-xforms/) -XForms processor allows developers to use XForms markup to create interactive web applications.